# Compiling Lua Rock vs Windows App's Lua.dll

Tags: windows, dll, lua, compilation

Is there a way to compile a Lua Rock against a Windows application's lua.dll (not my own)?

Specifically, the Binding of Isaac: Rebirth on windows has a lua5.3.3f.dll and lua5.3.3r.dll. The game can be modded with lua scripts, and I'd like to be able to use some Lua Rocks. I'm very new to dll's and Windows deployments.

Comment: What exactly do you want to use that needs C code of its own? I'd think that most things useful for modding a game like that would be pure Lua, and thus agnostic to the DLL.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica LuaFileSystem is the big one I'd like to add.

Comment: You don't link against a *.dll* but a *.lib*. I'm pretty sure the 3rd-party app doesn't ship that.